# Наклонение с "не то что" и "не то чтобы"

Tags: наклонение

Какие варианты являются правильными с точки зрения носителей языка и почему?

- а) Не то чтобы меня к ней физически тянуло, нет, просто меня привлекал склад её ума.
- б) Не то чтобы меня к ней физически тянет, нет, просто меня привлекает склад её ума.
- в) Не то что меня к ней физически тянуло, нет, просто меня привлекал склад её ума.
- г) Не то что меня к ней физически тянет, нет, просто меня привлекает склад её ума.

Answer (score 1):

Правильны первый вариант (пр. время) и второй (наст. время): "-бы" в обоих случаях отражает не реальную ситуацию, а гипотетическую, о которой можно "было бы" подумать (но правильнее сказать иначе). Отрицаемому противопоставляется нечто выраженное слабее и конкретнее (интерес к ней ограничен менее существенным):

```
Не то чтобы меня к ней физически тянуло - нет, просто меня привлекал склад её ума.

Меня к ней тянет не то чтобы физически - нет, просто меня привлекает склад её ума.
```

Конструкция с "не то что" возможна, но с противопоставлением более сильного: (не это или не просто это, а нечто большее):

```
Меня к ней не то что физически тянуло(-ет), а ещё и дрожь охватывала(-ет) в её присутствии.
```

(ср. Да, были люди в наше время, не то, что нынешнее племя - богатыри; М. Лермонтов)